# How to send invitation to Facebook friends on iOS using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, cordova

With exactly the same codebase I have perfectly working Facebook events on Android. However, on iOS it doesn't works. I'm using https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 for this and tried to set some alerts to see the error code or something (note `alert` in the code, for debugging purposes), but there is no action. In essence, I can't see any error, it just doesn't works. The following code:

```
this.options = {
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Play YellowSidd with me!'
};
this.onSuccess = function(result) {
   alert("Success with invite, result: " + result);
};
this.onError = function(msg) {
   alert("Failed with invite, msg: " + msg);
};

facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(this.options, this.onSuccess, this.onError);
```

In the Xcode in Build Phases -> Compile Sources I do have **FacebookConnectPlugin.m**. In Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries I do have also the following: **libsqlite3.dylib** (added by me), **Security.framework** (added by me), **Accounts.framework** (added by me), **Social.framework** (added by me). Also, the **FBSDKCoreKit.framework**, **FBSDKLoginKit.framework** and **FBSDKShareKit.framework**. These last 3 were already in that project.

Comment: @DarShan: cordova is for android and ios, and since it is working on android and not on ios, i would say the android tag is ok - it IS part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently an `actionType` is required when using this plugin on the iOS platform, even though on Android everything works fine without it. Ended up with the following code which works fine on iOS:

```
this.options = {
  actionType: '',
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Play YellowSidd with me!'
};
```